# Formula in VBA, putting a formula in a range of cells but excluding certain cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that will go to a range and insert a formula all the way down. The below code will go to range N17:N160 and insert a relative formula.

```
Sub Macro9()
    Range("n17:n160").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]="""","""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],R17C42:R160C53,7,FALSE),""""))"
End Sub
```

It works. However, I need to add a level where it looks at range B17:B160 and any cell in that range that has a "Y" in it will not update with the formula, whereas any one without a "Y", will update. Basically if and row has a Y in column B, don't put the formula in, for every other cell in the range, do put the formula in.

Thanks

First time posting, sorry if I didn't format everything correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to build a range reference that meest your criteria for adding the Formula,

Something like

```vb
Sub Macro9()
    Dim rng As Range, rngFiltered As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim idx As Long
    
    Set rng = Range("n17:n160")
    dat = rng.Offset(0, -12).Value2 ' Column B data
    rng.ClearContents ' Clear existing data from range
    For idx = 1 To UBound(dat)
        If dat(idx, 1) <> "y" Then
            If rngFiltered Is Nothing Then
                Set rngFiltered = rng.Cells(idx, 1)
            Else
                Set rngFiltered = Application.Union(rngFiltered, rng.Cells(idx, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rngFiltered.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-11]="""","""",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],R17C42:R160C53,7,FALSE),""""))"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The code doesn't error out, which is a miracle. I'll have to try and make sense of it to get it to work.

Comment: @Steve If this helps you with your problem don't forget to mark it as an answer!